# Where did Windows 10 save clipped images using Windows Key + Shift + S?

Tags: windows-10, clipboard, screenshot

When using <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, the selected area of the screen is copied to the clipboard.
Is it saved somewhere also as an image?  If so, where can I find it?

Comment: accepted answer is outdated as of 2022, see https://superuser.com/a/1754293/145072

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Edit: This answer is outdated. Please see new answers for the latest location, since it changes from time to time.**
<sup>I would edit this answer but I don't want to steal any current answers.</sup>

The new Snip & Sketch tool copies to the clipboard but will also save the image in a temp file. The temp file of the image is stored in AppData\Local.

> C:\Users%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_(a string of numbers and letters)\TempState\ScreenClip

Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/aia21t/snip_sketch/elt5ajt/

Comment: I was downvoted for providing a thoughtful answer here. People (lots of them) lose files storing them in temporary locations. I would never do such a thing.

Comment: Don't remember which answer you were but I didn't downvote any. OP should definitely save them elsewhere if they mean to keep them. This is a good place to look if they didn't save from clipboard and accidentally closed Snip & Sketch

Comment: That is what my answer was. They should be saved, not kept in a temporary locations. Yes, it was not you who downvoted.

Comment: Many thanks for the info.  Now I know the location, I can create a link to the folder since I clip a lot.

Comment: Folder exists but remains empty unfortunately. Could the location have changed since original answer?

Comment: Mine was stored in `...\Packages\MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_XXX\TempState`

Comment: @texasbruce YESSSSS thank you!

Comment: Update: In the recent builds, the path is different: `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Packages\MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy\TempState\ScreenClip`

Check out this page for more information → 
[Screenshot a Portion of the Screen in Windows 10 - Winkey+Shift+S](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/screenshot-portion-screen-windows-10-winkey-shift-s/)

Answer (score 10):

It looks like the location of temp files changed again :

> C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Packages\MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_(numbers and letters)\TempState\ScreenClip

Comment: This location is still valid as of 2021/07/21.

Comment: And 2021-11-19!

Answer (score 3):

2022-03 : New location :

```
AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.ScreenSketch_XXXXXXXXXX\TempState
```

Comment: This is the current location - 23 Dec 2022

Answer (score 0):

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Packages\MicrosoftWindows.Client.CBS_cw5n1h2txyewy\TempState\ScreenClip
```

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, click in address bar and paste the above destination.